# Restrict file type for a upload, ie only to show mp3

Tags: html

Is it possible to restrict the file upload for an form input to be only show files with the extension of mp3, like this:

```
<input class="someClass" type="file" name="UploadAudio" accept="audio/mp3"/>
```

Because for some reason this does not work, it always seems to show other file type extensions for upload.

Answer (score 33):

To specify an extension, start with the dot:

```
<input type="file" accept=".mp3,audio/*">
```

This will accept all files that have extension mp3 OR files of the Audio type. The comma allows to list multiple possibilities, so just remove the `,audio` if you strictly only want `.mp3` (and not `.wav` for example).

Your audio/mp3 is mixing both ways: either you use the extension OR the correct mime type, which should be `audio/mpeg3`

So your possibilities are:

```
<input type="file" accept=".mp3">
```

or

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/mpeg3">
```

Comment: Refer to MIME types for more information on where this `audio/mpeg3` came from and the other standard names.

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonse @Konerak, I tried the code above, it doesn't seem to work. Is it right for me to think that each browser will handle this accept attribute differently. I am currently using Firefox to test this.

Comment: It looks like Firefox only accepts audio/*|video/*|image/* and no mimetypes for the moment (v22). You can find them here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types

Answer (score 10):

To accept all kind of audio files, write all type of accepted extensions explicitly.

```html
<input type="file" accept="audio/mp3,audio/*;capture=microphone" />
```

this also hides the choose file button displayed on the screen.

Comment: For me (macOS 13.1, Google Chrome) it doesn't allow to choose .wav files